# How to rotate axes object in Matlab

Tags: matlab, rotation, axes

I'm looking for a way to rotate my image in axes in Matlab. I have tried to achieve this using `rotate` and `imrotate` but both functions don't work for me. Do anyone has an idea how to solve my problem?

```
imshow(imread('theImage.png'),'Parent',handles.axes3);

imrotate(handles.axes3, 45); %simply doesn't work
set(handles.axes3,'Rotation',45); %no 'Rotation' in axes
%I don't even know how to use just rotate()
```

Comment: show what you have tried then we can help you

Comment: Really? A minus because i posted only functions name instead of code?

Comment: although it may not necessarily deserve a downvote, just mentioning the name of the function you tried is not so helpful. The function might be the right one but called with the wrong parameters. If you're asking someone for help, let them know as much as you can instead of prompting several additional questions just to pinpoint your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to be clear, there is no way to rotate an `axes` object. But you can rotate the image data then display them again in their rotated state.

The function `imrotate` does rotate the "image data" you supply in input and return a matrix representing the rotated image data. So in your case, do not display directly after reading the file. Get the image data in a variable, rotate that with `imrotate`, then display the rotated image (or do what you need with it)

As an example:

```
img = imread('peppers.png') ; %// get the image data into the variable "img"
img2 = imrotate(img,90) ;     %// get the "rotated" image data into the variable "img2"

%// display both "img" and "img2"
subplot(1,2,1) ; imshow( img ) 
subplot(1,2,2) ; imshow( img2 )
```

will produce:
[image: rotated]